# Comparando conteúdo de strings em C para achar palíndromo

Tags: c, string

Preciso verificar se uma *string* A, por exemplo, é igual a *string* B pra determinar se a palavra inserida é um palíndromo, o problema é que a *string* B é o inverso da A, não estou conseguindo  determinar se os conteúdos são iguais. Por exemplo, eu entro com a palavra "arara", o programa deveria mostrar uma mensagem qua a palavra é um palíndromo, em vez disso ele mostra a mensagem que diz que a palavra não é um palíndromo.

```
#define N 20

int main()
{
    char palavra_a[N], palavra_b[N];
    int i,j=0,flag=0;

    puts("\nInsira uma palavra: \n");//pegando a palavra
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(palavra_a);

    for(i=strlen(palavra_a);i>0;i--)
    {
        palavra_b[j]=palavra_a[i];
        j=j+1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<strlen(palavra_a)-1;i++)
    {
        if(palavra_a[i]==palavra_b[i])
        {
            flag=0;
            printf("%c",palavra_b[i]);
        }
        else
        if(palavra_a[i]!=palavra_b[i])
        {
            flag=1;
            break;//caso a letra da palavra b seja diferente da palavra a, o laço é quebrado
        }

    }
    printf("\n  %s",palavra_b[N]);
    switch (flag)
    {
        case 0:
            puts("\nA palavra inserida eh um palindromo.");
        break;

        case 1:
            puts("\nA palavra inserida nao eh um palindromo.");
        break;
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: use a função `strcmp`, para o caso de não a ter carregado, faça `#include <string.h>`

Comment: mas eu preciso copiar ao contrario pra verificar se a palavra é palindroma

Comment: o que ele quis dizer é pra depois de copiá-la ao contrário, use só a strcmp() pra comparar. strcmp(palavra_a, palavra_b)

Comment: Pelo seu código vê-se algo diferente, porque pelo que você está agora a dizer no caso seria, **desacoplar**, **inverter**, **reagrupar** e por último comparar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Este código é complexo demais, simplificando ele fica bem mais fácil entender. Basta comparar o primeiro com o último, o segundo com o penúltimo caractere e assim por diante. Só precisa ir até metade já que a outra metade já foi comparada junto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 20

int main() {
    char palavra[N];
    printf("Insira uma palavra: ");
    scanf("%s", palavra);
    int tamanho = strlen(palavra);
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho / 2; i++) { //só irá até o meio
        if (palavra[i] != palavra[tamanho - i - 1]) {
            printf("\nA palavra inserida nao eh um palindromo.");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("\nA palavra inserida eh um palindromo.");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PXNkFf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jkvadmnk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Palindrome.c).

Comment: o codigo funcionou bem, mas se não for pedir mto, o que eu estava errando na outra logica?

Comment: Não sei, nem gastei tempo tentando entender por causa da complicação, optei por simplificar.

Answer (score 3):

> - aqui você está esquecendo do índice 0, nesse caso ta contando sempre ***+1*** caractere
> - voce esta também usando o **strlen**, que é uma função da biblioteca **<string.h>**
> - para resolver, *subtrai **-1*** aqui também e importa a biblioteca usando **#include <string.h>**

```
for(i=strlen(palavra_a) - 1; i>0; i--)
{
   palavra_b[j]=palavra_a[i];
   j=j+1;
}
```

> - aqui, não precisa de **elseif**,
> - porque se dois caracteres alfabéticos não são iguais, são diferentes
> - um **else** resolve isso

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(palavra_a)-1;i++)
{
    if(palavra_a[i]==palavra_b[i])
    {
       flag=0;
       printf("%c",palavra_b[i]);
    } else {
       flag=1;
       break;
    }
}
```

Podes também, criar uma função, mas usando o mesmo tipo de `loop` para inverter a palavra:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[10];

    puts("\nPalavra com 10 caracteres no maximo");
    gets(a);

    if(polindromo(a)){
        puts("sim e polindrome");
    } else {
        puts("nao e polindrome");
    }
    return 0;
}

int polindromo(char *a){
    int i,x;
    for(i = 0,x = strlen(a) - 1; i < x; ++i, --x){
        if(a[i] != a[x]){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

**O que acontece ?**

O que função *políndrome(char *arg)* faz, é declarar 2 variáveis `x` e `y`, onde uma delas terá como valor inicial `0` equivalente a posição do primeiro *caractere* numa *string*, e a outra terá como valor inicial, o tamanho da *string* passada no argumento dessa função **arg* menos *1* posição, porque o tamanho é sempre retornado contando à partir do *1* em vez do *0*. Logo compara-se, se a variável menor *i* é ainda menor que menor que a variável maior *x*, para a menor, faz-se um *incremento* sucessivo ao mesmo tempo que se *decrementa* a variável maior. Dentro do *loop*, no final, *i* terá o mesmo tamanho que *x*  antes do *loop ((tamanho_de_x) - 1)*. Logo, como um dos índices aumenta e outro diminui respectivamente os *caracteres* são comparados numa ordem inversa.

**Exemplo**

Não corresponde:

```
char a[6] = anatel

ordem a[i](+)  a[x](-)

1º    a        l
2º    n        e
3º    a        t
4º    t        a
5º    e        n
6º    l        a
```

Corresponde:

```
char a[5] = tenet

ordem a[i](+)  a[x](-)

1º    t        t
2º    e        e
3º    n        n
4º    e        e
5º    t        t
```

> Resposta também no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946655/program-that-checks-if-an-array-is-a-palindrome).

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, veja se isto lhe ajuda:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 20

int main(){
    char palavra_a[N], palavra_b[N];
    int i,j=0,flag=0;

    puts("\nInsira uma palavra: \n");//pegando a palavra
    gets(palavra_a);

    j=strlen(palavra_a)-1; 
    for(i=0;palavra_a[i]!='\0';i++){    
       palavra_b[j--]=palavra_a[a]; 
    }

    if (strcmp (palavra_a, palavra_b) == 0){
        flag=0;
    } else{
        flag=1;
    }

    printf("\n  %s",palavra_b[N]);
    switch (flag){
        case 0:
            puts("\nA palavra inserida eh um palindromo.");
        break;

        case 1:
            puts("\nA palavra inserida nao eh um palindromo.");
        break;
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```