# Inverter string em C - Problema com String com quantidade de caracteres par

Tags: c, array, string, for

Bem, tenho o código abaixo que deveria inverter uma string e mostrar se ela é um palíndromo. Porém, quando a palavra tem uma quantidade par de caracteres o resultado sai errado. Acho que o erro está no terceiro for, alguém consegue ver algum problema? Abaixo tem um exemplo da saída com o palíndromo "esse".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 21

int main (){
    char palavra[SIZE];
    int last;
    printf("Digite a palavra: ");
    scanf("%s", palavra);

    for (int i = 0; palavra[i] != 0; ++i) { // determina o fim da string
        last = i + 1;
    }

    char palavraReduzida[last], palavraInvertida[last]; // cria duas strings, uma com seu tamanho real e outra que vai ser invertida

    for(int i = 0; i <= last; ++i){
        palavraReduzida[i] = palavra[i]; //adiciona os caracteres a string de tamanho real
    }
    for(int i = 0; palavraReduzida[i] != 0; ++i) {
        palavraInvertida[i] = palavraReduzida[last - 1]; // Inverte a string
        --last;
    }

    printf("%s %d %s %d\n", palavraReduzida, sizeof(palavraReduzida), palavraInvertida, sizeof(palavraInvertida)); //Escreve a string invertida e a string de tamanho
    if(strcmp(palavraReduzida, palavraInvertida) == 0)       //Compara as strings                                  //Também mostra os tamanhos
        printf("E um palindromo");
    else
        printf("Nao e um palindromo");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E precisa fazer tudo isso por algum motivo ou pode fazer mais simples. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192842/101

Comment: Verdade, ajudou bastante, obrigado! Mas de qualquer forma, você saberia o porque de no final da string invertida aparecer esse caractere inesperado?

Comment: Por que você deixou de acrescentar o caractere terminador '\0'.

Comment: Boa noite! Por que não utilizar a função strrev() pra inverter sua string?
Ela está dentro da biblioteca string.h... Facilitaria muito sua resolução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não tá colocando o '\0' no final de palavraInvertida.

adiciona a seguinte linha antes do terceiro for:

```
palavraInvertida[last] = '\0';
```